# How to get last search letter in MultiAutoCompleteTextView in xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

After selecting the first value in multiselect it is not showing searched value in AutoCompleteTextView because it is taking the whole value of MultiAutoCompleteTextView Text. Please help me solve this issue.

```
private MultiAutoCompleteTextView text;    
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
       text = FindViewById<MultiAutoCompleteTextView>(Resource.Id.mulAuto);
       text.DropDownHeight = 500;
       text.Threshold = 1;
        text.TextChanged += text_TextChanged;

    }

  async void text_TextChanged(object sender, Android.Text.TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> str = new List<string>();
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        string API = "http://" + IPAddress + "/api/Test/getdata?searchstr=" + e.Text;
        var data = await client.GetStringAsync(API);
        JSONArray array = new JSONArray(data);

        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length(); i++)
        {
            str.Add(array.GetJSONObject(i).GetString("Name"));
        }

        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleDropDownItem1Line, str);
        text.Adapter = adapter;
        text.SetTokenizer(new MultiAutoCompleteTextView.CommaTokenizer());
    }
```

It is taking the previous selected value. Also, here is my code.

[image]

Comment: Have you looked over Android's guide on using MultiAutoCompleteTextView? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/MultiAutoCompleteTextView.html